# Continuity or not for being invertible

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse-function, monotone-functions

Let $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, I have read that if a function $f:X\to Y $ is CONTINUOUS and STRICTLY MONOTONE then is bijective from $X$ to $f(X)$.

My doubt is: the hypothesis of continuity is fundamental? I mean if a function is simply strictly monotone in $X$ then can I say that the function is bijective from $X$ to $f(X)$ and so $\exists f^{-1}:f(X)\to X$?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Are they subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes! I will edit the post!

Comment: Strictly monotone is enough.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy do you mean that continuity is not necessary?